# Is it possible to set style and JavaScript reference in a common place and use it all HTML page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I have more than 50 HTMl pages and in all pages I use style, javascript and bootstarp reference.

If I want to change style path then I have to do for all pages and it is time consuming task.

So is there any way so that I can define (global) my style, javascript and bootstarp in common way and share with all pages so that If I need to change style path then I have to do only one changes in global place.

For example : I have below 5 reference in all HTML pages.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/jquery.contextMenu.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/style.css">
 <script src="../scripts/constants.js"></script>
    <script src="../scripts/resources.js"></script>
    <script src="../scripts/utilities.js"></script>
```

Now if I want to change location of any style then I have to changes in all HTML pages.
Is there any way so We can declare reference path in a common place?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can take out the paths and make them global by declaring outside the functions so:

```
//declared once only
var css_path = "../styles/";
var js_path = "../scripts/";

//the below in all the HTML files
<link rel="stylesheet" href= css_path + "jquery.contextMenu.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href= css_path + "style.css">
<script src= js_path + "constants.js"></script>
<script src= js_path + "resources.js"></script>
<script src= js_path + "utilities.js"></script>
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue if you're 2 or more folders deep in to the structure.

Comment: @Ezani, Where Do I declare css_path and js_path? in any global js file?

Comment: You can declare it in any js file ONCE ONLY but outside any function (that's what makes it global).

Answer (score 0):

Just make all paths relative to the root of the site instead of relative to the current folder. You can do this by using the `/` prefix on the path:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/jquery.contextMenu.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/style.css" />
<script src="/scripts/constants.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/resources.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/utilities.js"></script>
```

Then you can put all of these references in a single server side include which you add to all relevant pages.

Comment: Thanks @Rory, I d not want to use relative path. I wan to to declare path at global level and use that path in HTML

Comment: For what reason? That's an anti-pattern at best, and just plain bad practice at worst.

Comment: I am using that HTML as a SharePoint web part and I upload all css and js file on site assets. This path is not same for all SharePoint client.

Comment: That's not a reason to not make all paths relative to the root.

Comment: Yes that is the reason because We have to upload all js and css on site assets and We create SharePoint page (which have different folder structure) and we use css and js over there and it is not working. So we need to change css and js reference in all html file based on SharePoint Page and site assets. So Is there any common place so we can change at one place and use that path in all html pages.

Comment: `we need to change css and js reference in all html file` you can still do that. My point is to make the path *relative to the root of the site*. Then it doesn't matter how many folders deep in to the structure the user is